# Why isn't my completion handler working with my URLSession?

Tags: swift, xcode, urlsession

I've run into a slightly problem in my app. Before I paste any code, let me provide a bit of context. I have a TableView with some dynamic cells. Each cell contains a button. When I press the button within the cell, a function is called which makes a URLSession datatask request. I use a Decodable class to store the JSON result and all I'm trying to do is print the count of the result array. The problem I have; the print is occurring before the result is returned.

To solve the problem, I've tried using a completion handler and run the URLSession inside a DispatchGroup and not print until the DispatchGroup ends.

I'm hoping somebody can take a quick look at my code and point out my mistake.

Here is my function where I make the URLSession request:

```
func loadLocalPrice(selectedItemName: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: [PriceModel])-> Void) {

    var localPrice = [PriceModel]()

    let urlApi = "http://my.url.com/category/"+self.selectedCategory+"/"+selectedItemName

    guard let url = URL(string: urlApi) else {return completion(localPrice)}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        self.dispatchGroupLoadItems.enter()
        do {
            localPrice = try JSONDecoder().decode([PriceModel].self, from: data)
            print("The result inside the function is: \(localPrice.count)")
        } catch let JSONerror {
            print("error decoding JSON", JSONerror)
        }
        self.dispatchGroupLoadItems.leave()

        }.resume()
        return completion(localPrice)
}
```

Here is the function that makes the call to the above function containing the URLSession:

```
    func addToBasket(sender: UIButton, name: String?, category: String?) {
    var localPrice = [PriceModel]()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loadLocalPrice(selectedItemName: name!) {
            (result: [PriceModel]) in
            print("got back inside the dispatchGroup: \(result.count)")

            localPrice = result
        }


        self.dispatchGroupLoadItems.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("Got back outside the dispatchGroup: \(localPrice.count)")
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my console output so you can see the order the results are returned:

```
got back inside the dispatchGroup: 0
Got back outside the dispatchGroup: 0
The result inside the function is: 1
```

Comment: you put return at wrong place keep it before "print("The result inside the function is: \(localPrice.count)")" this statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't need a `dispatchGroup` when you already have a completion handler. Your issue can be fixed by using the `completion` handler in a correct way as below,

```
func loadLocalPrice(selectedItemName: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: [PriceModel])-> Void) {

    var localPrice = [PriceModel]()

    let urlApi = "http://my.url.com/category/"+self.selectedCategory+"/"+selectedItemName

    guard let url = URL(string: urlApi) else { 
              completion(localPrice)
              return 
            }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
               completion(localPrice)
               return
             }
        do {
            localPrice = try JSONDecoder().decode([PriceModel].self, from: data)
        } catch let JSONerror {
            print("error decoding JSON", JSONerror)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion(localPrice)
        }
     }.resume() 
}

func addToBasket(sender: UIButton, name: String?, category: String?) {
    var localPrice = [PriceModel]()

    self.loadLocalPrice(selectedItemName: name!) {
        (result: [PriceModel]) in
        print("Count: \(result.count)")
        localPrice = result
    }
}
```

Comment: You should call completion(localPrice) after do {} block as if case of error it won't be called.

Comment: Thanks for response, and the explanation. Also thankyou for pasting my code back amended. The only change I made was to move the completion after the error check as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need dispatch group and return here.

```
 func loadLocalPrice(selectedItemName: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: [PriceModel])-> Void) {

      var localPrice = [PriceModel]()

      let urlApi = "http://my.url.com/category/"+self.selectedCategory+"/"+selectedItemName

      guard let url = URL(string: urlApi) else {
           completion(localPrice)
           return
      }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            completion(localPrice)
            return
        }
        do {
            localPrice = try JSONDecoder().decode([PriceModel].self, from: data)
            print("The result inside the function is: \(localPrice.count)"  
        } catch let JSONerror {
            print("error decoding JSON", JSONerror)
        }
        completion(localPrice)
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you'r trying to `return completion(localPrice)`.
First thing, `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)` is running on the background so you don't need to use `dispatchGroupLoadItems`.

All you have to do is to call you'r `completion block` on the main thread in the `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)` `completion block`, like that:

```
func loadLocalPrice(selectedItemName: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: [PriceModel])-> Void) {
    var localPrice = [PriceModel]()
    let urlApi = "http://my.url.com/category/"+self.selectedCategory+"/"+selectedItemName
    guard let url = URL(string: urlApi) else {
        completion(localPrice)
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            localPrice = try JSONDecoder().decode([PriceModel].self, from: data)
            print("The result inside the function is: \(localPrice.count)")
        } catch let JSONerror {
            print("error decoding JSON", JSONerror)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(localPrice)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And the `addToBasket` function becoming to:

```
func addToBasket(sender: UIButton, name: String?, category: String?) {
    var localPrice = [PriceModel]()

    self.loadLocalPrice(selectedItemName: name!) {(result: [PriceModel]) in
        print("The result from completion block: \(result.count)")

        localPrice = result
    }
}
```